# Please explain the rearrangement of the proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

From Valdimir A.Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, p. 270,
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Proposition 4 If a series $z_1+z_2+\dotsb+z_n+\dotsb$ of complex numbers converges
absolutely, then a series $z_{n_1}+z_{n_2}+\dotsb+z_{n_k}+\dotsb$ obtained by rearranging its terms also converges absolutely and has the same sum.

Proof $\qquad$ Using the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|$,  given a number $\varepsilon>0$, we choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|z_n|<\varepsilon$.

We then find an index $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that all the terms in the sum 
$S_N=z_1+\dotsb+z_N$ are among the terms of the sum $\tilde{s}_k=z_{n_1}+\dotsb+z_{n_k}$ for $k>K$. If $s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_n$, we find that for $k>K$
$$|s-\tilde{s}_k|\leq|s-s_N|+|s_N-\tilde{s}_k|\leq\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|z_n|+\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|z_n|<2\varepsilon$$

Thus we have shown that $\tilde{s}_k\to s$ as $k\to\infty$. If we apply what has just been proved to the series $|z_1|+|z_2|+\dotsb+|z_n|+\dotsb$ 
and $|z_{n_1}|+|z_{n_2}|+\dotsb+|z_{n_k}|+\dotsb$, we find that the latter series converges. Thus Proposition 4 is now completely proved.

The footnote says:
The term with index $k$ in this series is the term $z_{n_k}$ with index $n_k$ in the original series. Here the mapping $\mathbb{N}\ni k \mapsto nk\in\mathbb{N}$ is assumed to be a bijective mapping on the set $\mathbb{N}$.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Please explain the **rearrangement** of the proof, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a definition of "a series ... obtained by re-arranging its terms" ? Let $f: \Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ be a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N.$ For $k\in \Bbb N$ let $n_k=f(k)$  and let $y_k=z_{f(k)}=z_{n_k}.$ A re-arrangement of the $sequence$  $(z_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is $(y_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ and a re-arrangement of the series $\sum_nz_n$ is $\sum_ky_k$..... I dislike the notation $z_{n_k}$ because we are already using "$n$" (in "$z_n$") to denote a variable but in "$z_{n_k}$" , it denotes a function, i.e. $n_k=f(k).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes. Thank you very much. I’m confusing with the way of rearrangement, I think that the proof is exhibiting the generalized rearrangement, not specified way. The index mapping $\mathbb{N}  \ni k \mapsto n_k \in \mathbb{N}$, and the term $z_{n_k}$ is just some one term of original series, not specified one. Is it right?

Comment: A sequence $(z_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is actually a function $g:\Bbb N \to \Bbb C$ with $g(n)=z_n$ for each $n$. We take a bijection $f:\Bbb N to \Bbb N$ and make another sequence $(g(f(n)))_{n\in \Bbb N} .$